# How do I make a pink-powdered-sand grout to seal outdoor stone patio?

Tags: outdoor, patio, grout, stone, seal

I brought back some pink powdered sand from a recent vacation. I want to use it to grout and seal a stone patio I laid at the bottom of an outdoor stairwell with a drain. How should/can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Buy a mortar mix (or mix from scratch) and mix in your colored sand and mortar tinting until you get the desired color you’re looking for. See below:

https://www.google.com/search?q=mortar+coloring+powder&rlz=1CDGOYI_enUS900US900&oq=mortar+coloring&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i512l3j0i22i30l2.9880j0j7&hl=en-US&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

If you’re walking on it in the winter with the possibility of ice, use extra sand to develop some skid protection.

Practice in an isolated area and let your test samples completely dry to know the true color / texture.

Comment: Thank you. I have some mortar mix. But I more wanted to use white Portland cement and the sand. but maybe that will crumble?